# loop through folders and copy similar folders

Tags: python, loops, operating-system

with python how can i loop through folders and copy out subfolders with the same name from every folder and save it in a unique folder with the name. so A in test 1 and in test 2 should be copied to a folder called A and loop through doing the same for the rest[image: Dummy data]

i was able to loop through the main dir and got the dir(test 1 and test@) by using os.walk command

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import os, shutil

directory = "/home/martins/Desktop/Test/test1";
dest_dir = "/home/martins/Desktop/Test/test2";

filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, file))

for subFile in filelist:
    shutil.copy(subFile, dest_dir)

Comment: Updated to


import os, shutil

directory = "/home/martins/Desktop/Test/test1";
dest_dir = "/home/martins/Desktop/Test/test2";

filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dir in dirs:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, dir))
for subFile in filelist:
    shutil.copy(subFile, dest_dir)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import os, shutil;

directory = "/home/.../test1";
dest_dir = "/home/.../test2";

filelist = [];

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file));

for subFile in filelist:
    shutil.copy(subFile, dest_dir);
```

Comment: Your code copied everything from test1 to test2 but i want it to copy all file from A in test1 to A in test2 and from B in test1 to B in test2 and etc

Comment: So instead of copying the files lets copy the folders from each  test1 to test2

Comment: import os, shutil

directory = "/home/martins/Desktop/Test/test1";
dest_dir = "/home/martins/Desktop/Test/test2";

filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dir in dirs:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, dir))
for subFile in filelist:
    shutil.copy(subFile, dest_dir)

Comment: BUt get error on the last code